# Why spring boot do not run from intelij?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot

I am having problem to run my spring boot app from intellij.
When I make build and run jar from command line it works fine. But I can not run it from IntelliJ.
It looks like that when running from command line it loads `application.properties` file but when run from IntelliJ it doesn't load `application.properties` file.
Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = 'java-apns-notifier'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.10.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-web")

    //compile("com.relayrides:ios:0.4.3")
    compile files('libs/pushy/pushy-0.4.3.jar')
    compile("io.netty:netty-all:4.0.28.Final")
    compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1')

    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    compile("com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung:lutung:0.0.5")
    compile("com.google.guava:guava:18.0")
    runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}



eclipse {
    classpath {
        containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
        containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task copyResources(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/resources'
    into 'build/libs'
    exclude 'logback.xml'
}
processResources{
    exclude 'application.properties'
}
task myBuild(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = ['build', 'copyResources']
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.6'
}
```

I have following anotations on main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

This line in main class(Application.java) is where it breaks:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

This is the stacktrace:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'apnsMessageDAOImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
>   info.gandraweb.apns.repository.ApnsMessageDAOImpl.jdbcTemplate; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw
>   exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot
>   determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If
>   you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the
>   classpath.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)

and here is [my folder layout](http://i.imgur.com/jLq1LF7.png):

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: There are some tasks in your gradle build which are doing things with resources, why? If you have an `application.properties` in `src\main\resources` it should be read, if it in a different location nothing will happen.

Comment: After 2 days of debugging somehow I have succeed to run app from intellij. Apparently nothing changed.